# No picture on bing.com web page in chrome after 19.10 update

Tags: google-chrome, websites

I'm running 19.10 with MATE desktop.  Since the last update, the picture on the "bing.com" web page doesn't show up in chrome.  I have a second PC running 19.10 that had the pic show up, updated, and it disappeared.  My google-foo is not strong since I found no way to submit a bug report and didn't find anyone else had this problem. It's certainly not a big deal, but weird.

Comment: Delete your cache and try again.

Comment: Try with a newly created Linux user.

Comment: Simultaneously pressing Ctrl-Shift-Del will take you to the Chrome page where you can clear your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could've sworn I tried clearing cache before, but per comments from a couple helpful members, I tried clearing things again.  This fixed my issue.  I used "Advanced" and cleared everything but "passwords and other sign in data" and "all time" setting.